# Chrome extension for uncollapsing all Reddit comments on the post page

Tags: javascript, chrome, reddit

Given Reddit post which consist large amount of comments such as this one:

- [IAmA: We are Edward Snowden and the ACLU’s Jameel Jaffer.](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/36ru89/just_days_left_to_kill_mass_surveillance_under/)

I'm looking for Chrome compatible extension to scan the page for 'load more comments' links and uncollapse/load them all.

I've checked [Tampermonkey' user scripts at OpenUserJS](https://openuserjs.org/?q=reddit), but I didn't find any suitable scripts.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not an answer, but on the prowl for UserScripts you could also check with [GreasyFork](https://greasyfork.org/de/scripts?q=reddit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Reddit All Comments Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reddit-all-comments-viewe/djifpbcmaphjihhelcdeannijfelfnbh) extension for Chrome web-browser. It adds a button to *Load all comments* on Reddit page.

GitHub page: https://github.com/shadyabhi/reddit-all-comments-viewer

Read more at: [Reddit All Comments Viewer (Expand all comments in Reddit)](https://blog.abhi.host/blog/2012/03/21/chromium-extension-reddit-all-comments/) ([mirror](https://blog.abhijeetr.com/2012/03/chromium-extension-reddit-all-comments.html)).

Content Script used:

```
function runAgain(){
    //Run every one second
    window.setTimeout(addButton,1e3)
    }

function addButton(){
    //All buttons have class as "button"
    var first_button = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];
    if (first_button == null){
        alert("Sorry, no comments to expand");
        return;
    }

    if (first_button.innerHTML == "loading..."){
        first_button.className = ""; //To fix later
    }
    else{
       var theEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
       theEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
       first_button.dispatchEvent(theEvent);
    }

    if(first_button.id) 
        runAgain();
    };

//Link created and added as child to "pane"
var pane = document.getElementsByClassName("panestack-title")[0];
var newlink = document.createElement("a");
newlink.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Load all comments"));
newlink.id = "loadmorecomments";
newlink.href = "javascript:void(0)";
newlink.className="title-button ";
newlink.title = 'Opens all "load more comments" link every 1 second';
newlink.addEventListener('click', runAgain, false);
pane.appendChild(newlink);
```